# How to create multiple PWAs from a web app

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I want to make a web app where users can create albums, then make PWAs out of them at a sub route. What I want in the end is to have a url like myapp.com/username/app/randomAppId and when the user shares this link, the other party could install this on their mobile phone as a standalone album. I know what is required to make a PWA so the manifest and the service worker, but for this I would need to serve a different manifest for every app, so the user can pick the icon, colors and so on. What is a good solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters) `{username}/app/{appid}/manifest.json` in your app (PHP, Node.js, etc.), and dynamically build and return the content (In this case, `.json` manifest) just like other dynamic webpages.

You also need to set the correct `Content-type` when building response.

In vanilla PHP, for example:

```php
$manifest = [
    'name' => $album_name,
    'icons' => [
        // ...
    ],
];

// output manifest as JSON format
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($manifest);
```

(You need to refer to the framework's documentation if you are using a framework.)